# How to import numpy on python 3.8?

Tags: python, linux, numpy

I'm using ubuntu 20.04 and python3.6 and 3.8 are installed in my machine.When I run the code it gives me the output;

```
OpenCV bindings requires "numpy" package.
Install it via command:
    pip install numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: cannot import name 'multiarray' from partially initialized module 'numpy.core' (most likely due to a circular import) (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "19mayıs.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: cannot import name 'multiarray' from partially initialized module 'numpy.core' (most likely due to a circular import) (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py)
```

this is after I uninstalled numpy but before I uninstalled it. I got this error;

```
from. import add_newdocs

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <modul

from numpy.lib import add_newdoc File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/init.py", line 8, in <modul from .type_check

e>

import File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <mo Ddule> import numpy.core.numeric as _nx

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/init.py", line 26, in <mod ule>

raise ImportError(msg) ImportError:

lImporting the multiarray numpy extension module fatled. Most likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.

If you're working with a numpy git repo, try 'git clean -xdf (removes all files not under version control). Otherwise reinstall numpy. Je

Original error was: cannot import name 'multiarray' from parttally initialized odule 'numpy.core' (most likely due to a circular import) (/usr/lib/python3/dist -packages/numpy/core/init.py)
```

I thought numpy installation causes the problem so I reinstalled it. Still I have same problem. Is the problem about versions of library? Do you have any suggestions?

Firstly I tried few different deepsort libraries but nothing changed about the output.

Comment: maybe `pip3.8 install numpy` will solve it

Answer (score 1):

[Use a virtualenv and install your packages there.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)

Based on both `/usr/lib/python3.8/dist-packages` and `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` you're mixing-and-matching system-wide libraries installed for possibly different versions of Python.

In short,

```
$ python3.8 -m venv my-venv
$ source my-venv/bin/activate
$ pip install numpy opencv-python
$ python 19mayıs.py
```

Comment: This is also work properly. Are there another solutions?

Comment: I'm sure there's an infinite number of solutions, but using virtualenvs is the recommended one.